# Line End as a noun?

Tags: nouns

I am a bit confused with this, but is the word combination "line end" a legitimate noun? Could it be used in places where normally the longer form "end of line" is used?

Comment: Have you tried searching for examples of "line end?"

Comment: Or the even longer “end of the line”

Comment: @GArthurBrown I did and I found some here and there on the web, but I am still not quite sure whether it is an acceptable combination

Comment: Please provide the context. "End of line" is used only in certain circumstances. "...at the end of line 1" for instance.

Comment: You have to decide for yourself whether the words will be effective in communicating your meaning. The fact that the words appear on line somewhere doesn’t make them acceptable.

Comment: In an IT context we are more likely to use _line ending_. On my Linux  PC I have a text editor called Nano, and it detects if a text file has Unix or MS-DOS line endings.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Very useful hint, since my question area is also IT!